# Getting error "The parameter is incorrect" when using "Google Drive Desktop"

Tags: android, build

I use "Backup and Sync" to sync my project to Google Drive. It's OK.

Today, Google upgraded "Backup and Sync" to "Google Drive Desktop" and this app moved all my projects to a new drive G:, and the project path became "G:\my drive\projects..."

**G:\My Drive is a path created by "Google Drive Desktop" and cannot be changed**

Every file in G:\My Drive... can be opened, edited and copied

But, the projects in G:\my drive\projects... when open, get error **"The parameter is incorrect"**

How to fix this error
Thanks
[image: error:"The parameter is incorrect"]

Comment: If your path ends with  '...app\libs:' my guess would be that the colon at the end is screwing things up.

Comment: @mr.cook the colon just is descript for error message, it not include the code